# Matplotlib Tick lines and labels of different color

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, label

I am trying to plot a 2d image using a specific colormap in matplotlib and I need to change the color of the ticks to white. But when I do so, the labels or tick numbers change of color too and they become invisible on a white background.

How can I change only the color of the tick lines and not the color of their label or associated number???

Example

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np


    fig=plt.figure()
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111) 
    pc=ax.pcolormesh(xf,yf,F, vmin=F.min(), vmax=F.max(),  cmap=colormap)
    fig.colorbar(pc,orientation='horizontal',label=r'Intensity',format='%1.1f', ticks=np.arange(-0.1,0.6,0.1), pad=0.1)
    ax.set_xlabel("RA offset [arcsec]")
    ax.set_ylabel("DEC offset [arcsec]")
    ax.set_xlim(3.0,-3.0)
    ax.set_ylim(-3.0,3.0)

    ########## ticks

    ### x axis

    major_ticks = np.arange(-2.0, 3.0, 2.0)                                              
    minor_ticks = np.arange(-3.0, 4.0, 1.0)                                               


    ax.set_xticks(major_ticks)                                                       
    ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)                                           
    ax.set_yticks(major_ticks)                                                       
    ax.set_yticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)
```

Comment: Your example code does not run -- `xf`, `yf`, and `F` are not defined. Also, I don't see where you are trying to set the tick colors. Am I overlooking something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after making your `Axes` and setting the appropriate tick locations, you can access the ticks with `ax.get_xticklines()` and `ax.get_yticklines()`. If you iterate over all the `xticks` or `yticks`, you can change their colours using `set_color()`

For minor ticks, you can use `ax.xaxis.get_minorticklines()`. Note that you could also use `ax.xaxis.get_majorticklines()` in place of `ax.get_xticklines()` if you prefer.

```
for tick in ax.get_xticklines():
    tick.set_color('red')

for minortick in ax.xaxis.get_minorticklines():
    minortick.set_color('r')

for tick in ax.get_yticklines():
    tick.set_color('green')
```

Comment: Thanks! But the minor tick lines are still "black". Do you know a way to change them too??

Comment: For me this does not work. changes nothing

Answer (score 3):

Although the question is answered, I think that it is simpler to use

```
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', color='w')
```

to change the colour of the ticks of the y axis without changing the labels colour (the argument `which` chooses `major`, `minor` or `both`).

To change the colour of the ticks and labels the command would be

```
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', colors='w')
```

By simpler, I mean that it uses fewer lines to achieve the same result.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, as it would change the ticks' **and** the ticklabels' color.

Comment: How to set the alpha value using this method?